# how to check lookup table tags with documents tags

Tags: xslt

Halo,

I have this xml document:

```
<document>
<Line>
    <Line-Item>
        <ID>5</ID>
        <Quantity>100</Quantity>                
    </Line-Item>
</Line>
<Line>
    <Line-Item>
        <ID>6</ID>
        <Quantity>9</Quantity>              
    </Line-Item>
</Line>
<Line>
    <Line-Item>
        <ID>60</ID>
        <Quantity>3020</Quantity>               
    </Line-Item>
</Line>
</document>
```

And lookup file with table:

```
<lookup>
    <Code>
        <LookupID>5</LookupID>
        <LookupQuantity>25</LookupQuantity>
    </Code>
    <Code>
        <LookupID>6</LookupID>
        <LookupQuantity>3</LookupQuantity>
    </Code>
    <Code>
        <LookupID>70</LookupID>
        <LookupQuantity>3</LookupQuantity>
    </Code>
</lookup>
```

I should check  lookup tables field lookup/Code/LookupId with document Line/Line-Item/ID. if lookup/Code/LookupId=document/Line/Line-Item/ID then document/Line/Line-Item/Quantity=document/Line/Line-Item/Quantity div lookup/Code/LookupQuantity, otherwise document/Line/Line-Item/Quantity=document/Line/Line-Item/Quantity

Needed result:

```
<document>
<Line>
    <Line-Item>
        <ID>5</ID>
        <Quantity>4</Quantity>              
    </Line-Item>
</Line>
<Line>
    <Line-Item>
        <ID>6</ID>
        <Quantity>3</Quantity>              
    </Line-Item>
</Line>
<Line>
    <Line-Item>
        <ID>60</ID>
        <Quantity>3020</Quantity>               
    </Line-Item>
</Line>
</document>
```

My xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="date">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="skRez" match="LookupQuantity" use="../LookupID"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Line/Line-Item/Quantity">
        <xsl:variable name="inputS" select="..//ID"/>
        <xsl:variable name="inputQ" select="..//Quantity"/>
            <OrderedQuantity>
                <xsl:for-each select="document('lookup.xml')">
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('skRez',$inputS)">
                        <xsl:variable name="Quantity" select="."/>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$Quantity"><xsl:value-of select="ceiling($inputQ div $Quantity)"/></xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$inputQ"/></xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>                       
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </OrderedQuantity>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: can you add the xslt which you attempted to perform this? also in the needed result where do you get quantity 4 for the ID 5 Line-Item?

Comment: @Treemonkey: I add it, there doesn't work otherwise, I mean didn't take $inputQ result.

Comment: quantity should be 25 for the ID 5?

Comment: for ID 5 should be quantity/lookupQuantity=100/25=4. for ID 6 should be 9/3=3, for id 60 quantity=3020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you can define a variable to hold the look-up data

```
<xsl:variable name="lookup" select="document('Lookup.xml')/lookup"/>
```

And then you can look-up the quantity for a particular Line-Item like so (In this case, the XSLT is currently positioned on a Quantity element within a Line-Item)

```
<xsl:variable name="quantity" 
  select="$lookup//Code[LookupID = current()/../ID]/LookupQuantity"/>
```

If nothing was returned by this variable, then you know the element was not in the look-up

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:variable name="lookup" select="document('Lookup.xml')/lookup"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Line-Item/Quantity">
      <xsl:variable name="quantity" 
         select="$lookup//Code[LookupID = current()/../ID]/LookupQuantity"/>
      <Quantity>
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="number($quantity) = number($quantity)">
               <xsl:value-of select="number(.) div number($quantity)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </Quantity>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<document>
   <Line>
      <Line-Item>
         <ID>5</ID>
         <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      </Line-Item>
   </Line>
   <Line>
      <Line-Item>
         <ID>6</ID>
         <Quantity>3</Quantity>
      </Line-Item>
   </Line>
   <Line>
      <Line-Item>
         <ID>60</ID>
         <Quantity>3020</Quantity>
      </Line-Item>
   </Line>
</document>
```